# JSF PrimeFaces rendering components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Let's say I have a simple method that, like this:

```
public String test()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

Now let's say I have the following PrimeFace component:

```
        <p:fieldset styleClass="containers" rendered="#{controller.test()}">

            <h2>Testing</h2>

            <p:outputLabel for="test" value="Test" />
            <p:inputText id="test" />

        </p:fieldset>
```

The method above returns "hello". I would like to dynamically show and hide that fieldSet by comparing the returned value of that method to a field of one of my beans. For instance, on the rendered parameter, I would like to do something like: controller.test() != "some variable" which would return true or false. Am I allow to do that? If not, what is the way of doing it?

Basically the goal is to dynamically show and hide some container by comparing the returned value of a method with a bean property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look Like you misunderstood  `rendered`

**The rendered Attribute**

> A component tag uses a Boolean EL expression, along with the rendered
>   attribute, to determine whether or not the component will be rendered.

If you will check above definition you will know what exactly is the use of this attribute.

More you can see below

> The rendered attribute which uses Boolean EL expression indicates
>   whether a component is currently visible or not. The property is
>   useful when you want to hide components for specific users or based on
>   condition. The default value of rendered attribute is true.

```
<h:outputText value=”mapping” rendered=”Boolean EL expression” />
```

For example, the commandLink component in the following section of a page is not rendered if the cart contains no items:

```
<h:commandLink id="check"
    ...
    rendered="#{cart.numberOfItems > 0}">
    <h:outputText
        value="#{bundle.CartCheck}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

With your concrete problem you can do like this

- Make a `String` variable call `value`
- Now create get/set methods for above variable

Now in your test method you can add

```
public void test(){
       value="hello";
      }
```

Bur remember you have call `test()` method of page load

Now in your Xhtml or Jsf or Jsp page

```
rendered="#{controller.value != 'hello'}"
```

Or better way create a `Boolean`  variable and do all the magic of hide and show the component

Comment: It is not working actually (I thought it would) but I think is because I need to use the .equals method. How do I use the equals method instead of == or !=?

Comment: it should work ...FYI you can use  `rendered="#{controller.value.equal('hello')}"`